# How do I order by row.names in dataframe

Tags: r

This is rather tricky, and it doesn't seem to require the same approach for ordering by a typical column in a data frame. I have something that looks like this:
[image]

And would like it be ordered by row.names.

What I've tried:

`dataframename[ rownames(dataframename) , ]` does not seem to work, nor does `dataframename[ order(rownames(dataframename) , ]`, infact what I get with the latter option is an ordering of  1,10,100, 12,13, ...,2,20,21,.

Can `arrange` from the `plyr` library remedy this?

Comment: like.... what? (you didn't add the example)

Comment: Are you sure `dataframename[ order(rownames(dataframename)) , ]` doesn't work? Can you give such an example?

Comment: OK. I'm going to guess you want them sorted by the numeric version of the row.names (row names for data.frames are always characters) `dataframename[ order(as.numeric(rownames(dataframename))) , ]`

Comment: @MrFlick going to try that out...and...it works!

Comment: Given the fact that you have (apparently) just downvoted an earlier answer I gave, are you paying attention to the fact that `"rownames" != "row.names"` AND that there is a 'row.names' attribute for all dataframes?

Comment: @BondedDust I'm aware `"rownames" != "row.names"`. Anyway, `dataframename[ order(as.numeric(rownames(dataframename))) , ]` as suggested by MrFlick works, and that is despite `"rownames" != "row.names"` ! I meant no offense in downvoting. I'm just simply indicating that the method you suggested did not address the problem correctly.

Comment: .... because the "problem" was not posed with an example that supported testing (either yours or the one you downvoted. There is a difference in columns that are of numeric class and those of character class. Compare: `order( as.character(1:11) )` and `order( 1:11 )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this problem before.  Here's how I solved it. Using some `iris` sample data from base R,

```
> dat <- iris[sample(nrow(iris), 10), ]
> rn <- rownames(dat)
> dat[order(as.numeric(rn)), ]
```

Comment: Ah yes, that's what @MrFlick suggested in the comments below my query and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Ordering by a column should be as simple as:

```
 dataframename[ order(dataframename$row.name) , ]
```

Notice that your first column is named `row.names` but it's not clear if you meant that picture to refer to a dataframe where the rownames were real R rownames and not the first column. Assuming that is that `"row.name" == names(dataframename)[1]`. Please check whether this condition is true. At the moment you have given only a picture, whereas it would have been more helpful to provide the results of `dput( dataframename[ 1:22, ])`

Comment: thank you for the attempt at helping. I actually tried that method too and it didn't work. I get `Error in order(trainFullProbs$rowname) : argument 1 is not a vector`, but that makes sense since row.names entries are characters.

Comment: You seem to be missing the fact that "rowname" != "row.name" AND the the fact that the `row.name` function applied to the "dataframename" is NOT the same as the `$`-function applied to the expression `row.name` when the dataframe has a column named "row.name".